# api call using retrofit not working in android

Tags: android, onclick, butterknife

I am working on a demo app for learning retrofit,I have used retrofit in app and went step by step.can anyone help me?
I have used @onclick annotation for making click event but it is never executing when i am clicking a button.So can anyone tell me what is the wrong from myside?

```
 void getContacts() {
ApiInterface apiService =
        ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
Call<ContactRespones> call = apiService.getContacts();
call.enqueue(new Callback<ContactRespones>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ContactRespones> call, Response<ContactRespones> response) {
        System.out.print("RESPONES---------------->" + response.body().toString());
        List<ContactRequest> movies = response.body().getContacts();
        Log.d(TAG, "Number of movies received: " + movies.size());
        //  recyclerView.setAdapter(new MoviesAdapter(movies, R.layout.list_item_movie, getApplicationContext()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ContactRespones> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
    }
});
```

}

**

Comment: Your gradle ....?

Comment: @siva35 -added in edit.Please check

Comment: Reffer this http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

Comment: Add annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'

Comment: It gives me error whiile gradle building.

Answer (score 2):

Add `annotationProcessor` to your gradle, and rebuild gradle and project:

```
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
```

In your casae it will be like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code should be like below.

```
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    @BindView(R.id.btn_1)
    Button button;
    @BindView(R.id.lv_contacts)
    RecyclerView lv_contacts;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btn_1)
    public void buttonclick() {
        button.setText("Clicked!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

onCreate:
`Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
btn.setOnClickListener(this);`
get an OnClickListener:
Override/implement Methods...
then in the OnClick:
`if(view.getId()==btn_1){
 do sth.
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this in Button view

```
android:onClick="buttonclick"
```

so It will look like:

```
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:onClick="buttonclick"
    android:text="Get Contacts"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        ## In your java code use: ##

        @InjectView(R.id.btn_1)
        Button button;

         @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                ButterKnife.inject(this);


            }

            @OnClick(R.id.btn_1)
            void submitButton(View view) {
                if (view.getId() == R.id.btn_1) {

                    Toast.makeText(this, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

    ## in your activity_main.xml : ##

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">


        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/btn_1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="59dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="59dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="132dp"
            android:onClick="submitButton"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

## in build.gradle file(app) ##

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
}
```

Comment: It says "can not resolve symbol" when i am adding InjectView.!

Comment: have u added all the dependencies  in build.gradle?

Comment: can you check my gradle please? is anything missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found the older version of butterknif is working fine using @Bind annotation,i have changed dependency version of butterknife in gradle as below and its working very fine.

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
```

Comment: Great it's working! But It should work with newest version too. A lot of changes and fixes were made in newer versions: https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md Try to figure it out, but main problem in your case was gradle dependency ;)